# Add 1 month to date and also display correct time from timestamp

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I run this query on `redshift` to add 1 momth to a specific `timestamp` that:

```
SELECT
DATEADD(month, 1, date '2021-08-12 18:37:19') AS date_interval;
```

The result is this:

```
2021-09-12 00:00:00.0
```

How do I need to modify the query so the result also comes with the correct `time` looking like this:

```
2021-09-12 18:37:19
```

Comment: Use `add_month()` instead.

Comment: I tried but the issue remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do algebra on a timestamp, then you should start with a literal `timestamp`, not a `date`:

```sql
SELECT
    DATEADD(month, 1, '2021-08-12 18:37:19') AS date_interval;
```

The problem with your current query is that the following is a *date* literal:

```
date '2021-08-12 18:37:19'
```

Hence, the time component of your timestamp will be "zeroed" out to midnight before you even add one month.